# Subtract two times in Date Field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns meant to keep time for late employees. below is a sample of their content:

```
select TO_CHAR(VAHRUAE_ActualInTime, 'HH24:MI') ActualTime, TO_CHAR(VAHRUAE_InTime, 'HH24:MI') InTime from VAHRUAE_DailyAttendance

ActualTime          InTime
   01:25             00:57
   05:46             00:57
   06:00             00:57
```

I want to subtract ActualTime from Intime. I searched a lot on the internet and tried lots of ideas but didn't find the solution.  I thought about splitting hour from minute and subtract, then join them. problem with this that negative values will show(such as 46-57 will result -11min). what is the right solution for this.
Update:
the result should be in hour:min form, something like:
 
05:03 (which is from 06:00-00:57)

(if it helps)

```
select VAHRUAE_ActualInTime ActualTime, VAHRUAE_InTime InTime from VAHRUAE_DailyAttendance

  ActualTime            InTime
--------------         --------
   01-JAN-70             00:57
   01-JAN-70             00:57
   01-JAN-70             00:57
```

```
desc VAHRUAE_DailyAttendance

Name                          Type
----------                   ------
VAHRUAE_ActualInTime          Date
VAHRUAE_InTime                Date
```

Comment: i have provided  suggested answer ..let me know if it works

Comment: Can you please share the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(ActualTime) - TO_TIMESTAMP(InTime) FROM VAHRUAE_DailyAttendance;
```

OR other way:

```
SELECT (ActualTime - InTime)*24*60 AS difference_in_minutes from VAHRUAE_DailyAttendance;
```

This value is negative if `ActualTime` is lies in the past. If you want an integer value then round the result

```
select round((ActualTime - InTime)*24*60,0)
  from test;
```

Comment: your second and third query works well
`SELECT Round ((VAHRUAE_ActualInTime - VAHRUAE_InTime)*24*60) AS difference_in_minutes from VAHRUAE_DailyAttendance`, but how to convert it to hour:min format